# How to allow empty string in regex ColdFusion?

Tags: javascript, regex, coldfusion

I have done my regular expression in JavaScript and my regex allows alpha characters, numbers, space and empty string. i would like the same regular expression in ColdFusion. I have everything working fine but empty string. Here is my JavaScript:

```
/^([A-Z0-9 ]{1,50})?$/i
```

and here is what I have in ColdFusion:

```
<cfset match = REMatch("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,50}$",myText)>
```

this will match everything I want but empty string. I can not use `?` in ColdFusion because that will look to match any character in the string. If anyone knows how to match an empty string please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Try setting the min value to `0`  -  `<cfset match = REMatch("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,50}$",myText)>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That works fine. Is that reliable or there is some case where this can crash? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There should be no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the min value to `0`

```
<cfset match = REMatch("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,50}$",myText)>
                                      ^
```

The [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) allows setting both thresholds, min and max. When you set the min value to 0, it will allow matching nothing, empty string.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,50}` - 0 to 50 ASCII letters, digits or spaces
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: What will be in the case when I have to require 3 digits or empty space. I can't use {0,3}, I need something that will accept 3 digits or empty string.

Comment: Use alternation: `"^([A-Za-z0-9 ]{3,50}|)$`